# Serde Deserialize lifetime interfering with local variable lifetime

Tags: rust, serde

I am learning Rust and playing with Tokio, channels and Serde. I am having difficulty writing some very basic code:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver};

struct WorkflowProcess {
    rx: Receiver<String>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Msg {
    version: i32,
}

impl WorkflowProcess {
    async fn process<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(&mut self, callback: impl Fn(T)) {
        let r = self.rx.recv().await;
        if let Some(v) = r {
            let s: &str = v.as_str();
            let deserialized: T = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
            callback(deserialized);
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel::<String>(100);
    let mut workflow = WorkflowProcess { rx };
    let worker = tokio::spawn(async move {
        let x = |msg: Msg| {
            assert_eq!(
                msg.version,
                32
            );
        };
        workflow.process(x).await;
    });
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&Msg { version: 32 }).unwrap();
    tx.send(serialized).await;
    worker.await;
}
```

Trying to compile gives me this error:

```
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:27
   |
14 |     async fn process<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(&mut self, callback: impl Fn(T)) {
   |                      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
17 |             let s: &str = v.as_str();
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
18 |             let deserialized: T = serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap();
   |                                   ----------------------- argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'a`
19 |             callback(deserialized);
20 |         }
   |         - `v` dropped here while still borrowed
```

It seems to me the `deserialized` lifetime falls within the lifetime of `v` and `s`, but I am guessing `'a` is not what I think it is. I wish there was a lifetime debugger/visualizer for Rust. Is `'a` same as `'static` in this case?

I know I can use `DeserializeOwned`, but I really wanted to get to the bottom of my misunderstanding.

Comment: The problem is that `'a` will be chosen by whomever calls `process`, so it can be anything up to and including `'static`. The standard solution for this use case is to use an [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), but I'm not sure how to do that with a lifetime parameter (as in `Deserialize<'a>`) rather than a plain reference (as in `&'a T`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) as @Jmb suggested in the comments:

```rust
impl WorkflowProcess {
    async fn process<T>(&mut self, callback: impl Fn(T))
    where
        for<'a> T: Deserialize<'a>,
    {
        let r = self.rx.recv().await;
        if let Some(v) = r {
            let deserialized: T = {
                let s: &str = v.as_str();
                serde_json::from_str(s).unwrap()
            };
            callback(deserialized);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=765af3b56112850f185d3f8558bfccf5)

Comment: Thank you and @Jmb. That HRTB thing was on my list of things to read but now it got to the top ;).

Comment: `for<'a> Deserialize<'a>` is just [`DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html).